# Directions Reduction JavaScript - I can not find my error

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

In this problem we have to transform an array of moves to avoid going back to the same place while keeping only the important instructions. The problem is that once I thought I had solved it, the result is not what I expected, could someone guide me about the error in my code?

```
function dirReduc(arr){
  let y = 0,
      index = 0,
      directions = [];
  
  arr.forEach(function(movement){
    if(movement == "NORTH"){
      if(directions.includes("SOUTH")){
        index = directions.indexOf("SOUTH")
        directions.splice(index, 1)
      } else{
        directions.push("NORTH")
      }
    } 
    
    else if(movement == "SOUTH"){    
      if(directions.includes("NORTH")){
        index = directions.indexOf("NORTH")
        directions.splice(index, 1)
      } else{
        directions.push("SOUTH")
      }
    } 
    
    else if(movement == "EAST"){
      if(directions.includes("WEST")){
        index = directions.indexOf("WEST")
        directions.splice(index, 1)
      } else{
        directions.push("EAST")
      }
    } 
      
      else if(movement == "WEST"){
      if(directions.includes("EAST")){
        index = directions.indexOf("EAST")
        directions.splice(index, 1)
      } else{
        directions.push("WEST")
      }
    }
  });
  
  return directions
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way of doing it, canceling out opposite moves and listing them in an ordered way:

```js
const dirs=["north","north","west","south","west","north","east","north","west","south"];

const rd=dirs.reduce((a,c)=>(++a[c],a),
 {north:0,east:0,south:0,west:0});
let ns=rd.north-rd.south,
  ew=rd.east-rd.west;
const res=(ns?Array(Math.abs(ns)).fill(ns>0?"north":"south"):[])
   .concat(ew?Array(Math.abs(ew)).fill(ew>0?"east":"west"):[]);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that way. Thank you for taking the time to help me